# AngularJS orderBy date

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have something like this:

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in inv">
      <p>{{i.dueDate}}</p>
  </div>
```

I'd like to order by oldest date first. I know there's a way to do it but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Here is the sample js:

```
 $scope.inv = [
    {
        name: "Paul",
        dueDate: "5/21/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Dan",
        dueDate: "5/22/2014"
    },
    {
        name: "Randy",
        dueDate: "1/12/2015"
    }
 ];
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=angularjs%20orderby%20date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a customizer function, then use it in `orderBy` expression. For example:

```
$scope.dueDateFormatter = function(i) {
   var dateParts = i.dueDate.split(/\//);
   return dateParts[2] 
       + '-' + (dateParts[0] < 10 ? '0' + dateParts[0] : dateParts[0]) 
       + '-' + (dateParts[1] < 10 ? '0' + dateParts[1] : dateParts[1]);
};

<div ng-repeat="i in inv | orderBy:dueDateFormatter">
   <p>{{i.dueDate}}</p>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZPw5T7K2BUCMjV1BFRSz?p=preview). The function basically reorders the date string, so that Year comes first, Month next and Day last. If you use `moment.js` or similar library, you can use their parsers instead.

Comment: could you confirm dueDate is sorting properly?

Comment: Sorry, don't get what you mean. Of course, using `orderBy:'dueDate'` only won't solve the case: those values will be sorted as strings, not dates. Therefore '1/1/2015' will be considered 'older' than '2/31/2014', for example.

Comment: this answer works better for my needs since the dates are being received as strings. thanks @raina77ow

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in inv | orderBy:'-dueDate'">
  <p>{{i.dueDate}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your strings to YYYY-MM-DD format

`<li ng-repeat="item in inv | orderBy:orderByDate">{{item.name}} </li>`

```
$scope.orderByDate = function(item) {
var parts = item.dueDate.split('/');
var date = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], parseInt(parts[0]), parseInt(parts[1])));

return date;
```

};

***Demo***
http://plnkr.co/edit/o6fCDyiqkkU9YVWwZC09?p=preview