# Angular JS orderBy is not working with Dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

`orderBy` feature is not working with the dates when i try to use in the `ng-repeat`

Here I wanted to sort the entried based on the `executedOn`

I wanted to sort element the latest date should be reflected at the top.

Can someone help me

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.details = [
  {
    "id": 255463,
    "orderId": 226433,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "25/Sep/17",
    "executedBy": "Person A",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person A",
    "cycleId": 4042,
    "cycleName": "Cycle A",
    "versionId": 21289,
    "versionName": "Version A",
    "issueKey": "A"
  },
  {
    "id": 255433,
    "orderId": 226403,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "1/Mar/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4041,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 21289,
    "versionName": "Version A",
    "issueKey": "B"
  },
  {
    "id": 255432,
    "orderId": 226402,
    "status": 1,
    "executedOn": "1/Apr/17",
    "executedBy": "Person B",
    "executedByDisplay": "Person B",
    "cycleId": 4041,
    "cycleName": "Cycle B",
    "versionId": 21289,
    "versionName": "Version A",
    "issueKey": "C"
  }
];
});
```

```css
th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">


  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="table h6">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Cycle Name</th>
            <th>Execution Completed</th>
            <th>Total Test Cases</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in details | orderBy :'executedOn'">
          <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
          <td>{{x.cycleName}}</td>
          <td>{{x.executedOn | date:'d-MMM-yy'}}</td>
          <td>{{x.versionName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: just have a look at :
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080669/angularjs-orderby-date) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876116/angular-orderby-date)

Comment: @a.u.b No I have gone through that before posting question, My Problem its not even doing orderBy at all, The one you said above that is having issue with reverse orderBy

Comment: @Mozhdeh.Hamidi Thanks I am checking them!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about to convert `"executedOn"` to `Date` Object:   `new Date("25/Sep/17"),`

You can do that as:

```
$scope.details.map(function(item){
    item.executedOn = new Date(item.executedOn);
    return item;
  });
```

The sorting will work properly

```
    <tr ng-repeat="x in details | orderBy :'executedOn'">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{x.cycleName}}</td>
      <td>{{x.executedOn | date:'d-MMM-yy'}}</td>
      <td>{{x.versionName}}</td>
    </tr>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0H9vqjfsQzYei1xWLGQ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks !! Worked like charm

Comment: Any reason this behave different in Chrome and Firefox , Is there any way to handle that

Comment: I could able to handle using date.js framework thanks!! [http://www.datejs.com/](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use A getter function as orderBy expression. This function will be called with each item as argument and the return value will be used for sorting.  [**see details in demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/A2S6MuZz83CbGkGmBhrp?p=preview)

**js**

```
$scope.makerightorder = function(x){
   return new Date(x.executedOn);
}
```

**obviously use true as 2nd argument to see latest first**

**html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in details | orderBy :makerightorder:true ">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{x.cycleName}}</td>
    <td>{{x.executedOn | date:'d-MMM-yy'}}</td>
    <td>{{x.versionName}}</td>
 </tr>
```